# Problemas con la subida de archivos

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, upload

En un proyecto con Laravel, Vuejs y Axios, dentro de lo que es la vista de detalle de un usuario, dentro del mismo formulario que sirve para actualizar sus datos, estoy tratando de actualizar, igualmente, su imagen de usuario o avatar.

He decidido que la carpeta para almacenar las imágenes de los usuarios sea esta: "./storage/app/public/images/profile" (ejecutando "php artisan storage:link", creé el enlace simbólico dentro de "./public" de tal forma que ya dispongo de "./public/storage/images/profile").

Resumiendo un poco el contenido del formulario del componente UserProfEditComponent.vue que carga todos los datos referidos al usuario seleccionado, yendo a lo importante, éste sería el código del mencionado componente:

[**UserProfEditComponent.vue**]

```
<template>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">
        <form @submit.prevent="updateReg()" class="form-horizontal" novalidate>
            <!-- ... -->
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-4 mb-1">
                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8 mx-auto text-center">
                                <img class="input-img-avatar" :src="avatar" alt="Imagen de usuario seleccionada">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mt-0">
                            <div class="col-8 mx-auto text-center">
                                <label class="btn-bs-file btn btn-primary">
                                    Cargar nuevo avatar
                                    <input type="file" name="avatar" @change="getNewAvatar" accept="image/*" ref="inputFileAvatar" />
                                </label>
                                <span v-if="errors.has('avatar')" class="block text-sm text-danger mt-2">{{ errors.get('avatar') }}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 text-right">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" title="Actualizar registro">Actualizar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Con la parte de estilos que expongo, el input de file no llega a ser visible y de lo que se dispone del label "Cargar nuevo avatar" que se encarga de abrir el panel para seleccionar la imagen pasando dicho archivo al Input file.

```
.btn-bs-file{
    position:relative;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.btn-bs-file input[type="file"]{
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999999;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    outline: none;
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

En la parte de SCRIPT del componente, dispongo de todo esto:

```
<script>

    //librería para tratar los errores capturados en el servidor
    import { Errors } from '../../libs/errors';
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.');

            //Recibiendo evento(s) si emitido(s) (en este caso, desde su componente Padre)
            BusEvent.$on('fillProfEditFormEvent', (regID) => {
                this.fillEditFormReg(regID);
            });
        },

        //datos devueltos por el componente:
        data() {
            return {
                urlBase: '/api/admin/users',
                //variable que guarda el archivo seleccionado
                //indicando nombre del archivo precedido de la ruta completa
                //hacia el archivo guardado en el servidor
                avatar: null,
                avatar_max_size: null,
                //variable para almacenar los datos del registro a almacenar
                //objReg: {},
                objReg: {
                    'name': '',
                    'lastname': '',
                    'phone_int': '',
                    //y más datos que no pongo para que no sea más largo
                    'avatar': '',
                    //para la edición
                    'id': '',
                },
                //posibles errores
                errors: new Errors(),
            }
        },

        methods: {

            /**
             * Mostrando datos cargados del registro para editar
            */
            fillEditFormReg(regID) {
                console.log('Cargando datos del registro correspondiente [' + regID + ']');
                let url = this.urlBase + '/' + regID;
                axios.get(url)
                .then(response => {       //SI TODO OK
                    console.log(response.data)
                    //this.objReg = response.data
                    //this.objReg = response.data.user
                    this.objModelDependenciesLists = response.data.dependenciesLists

                    this.objReg = {
                        'name': response.data.user.name,
                        'lastname': response.data.user.lastname,
                        'phone_int': response.data.user.phone_int,
                        //...
                        'avatar': response.data.user.avatar,
                        //...
                        //para la edición
                        'id': response.data.user.id,
                    };
                    this.avatar_max_size = response.data.user_icon_max_size
                    this.avatar = `/storage/images/profile/${this.objReg.avatar}`
                    //carga inicial de la imagen precedida de su ruta

                })
                .catch(error => {           //SI HAY ALGÚN ERROR
                    console.log(error.response.data.errors);
                });
            },

            /**
             * Lanzado al cambiar el valor del input de archivo del formulario
            */
            getNewAvatar(e) {
                let file = e.target.files[0];
                //Sacando características referidas al archivo cargado
                //en el input de archivo dentro de un array JSON
                console.log(file);

                if(file['size'] <= this.avatar_max_size) {
                    //Leyendo el archivo cargado
                    this.readFile(file);
                } else {
                    //Reseteando valor...
                    this.cancelFileAction();
                    alert('El archivo cargado tiene un tamaño en disco más grande de lo permitido.');
                }
            },

            readFile(file) {
                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                reader.onload = e => {
                    //Pasando la imagen seleccionada en Base64 a la variable
                    //que se caraga en la etiqueta IMG
                    this.avatar = e.target.result;
                    console.log('Esto es ahora AVATAR: ' + this.avatar)
                    //Asignando la imagen seleccionada en Base64 a
                    //la propiedad 'avatar' del objeto objReg
                    this.$set(this.objReg, 'avatar', e.target.result)
                }
            },

            cancelFileAction() {
                //Reseteando imagen y volviendo a valor anterior...
                this.avatar = `/storage/images/profile/${this.objReg.avatar}`;
                //Limpiando elementos...
                this.clearFileAction();
            },

            clearFileAction() {
                //Reseteando imagen y volviendo a valor anterior...
                //Reseteando contenido del INPUT File
                const input = this.$refs.inputFileAvatar;
                input.type = 'text';
                input.type = 'file';
            },

            /**
             * Actualizando registro
            */
            updateReg() {
                console.log('Actualizando registro... [' + this.objReg.id + ']');
                let url = this.urlBase + '/' + this.objReg.id;
                axios.put(url, this.objReg)
                .then((response) => {       //SI TODO OK

                    //vaciando los posibles errores que se produjeron
                    this.errors.clear();

                    //Emitiendo evento global para recargar
                    //en el  panel izquierdo de datos resumen
                    //  >> con el ID pasado
                    BusEvent.$emit('fillProfDataResumEvent', this.objReg.id);

                    //Lanzando notificación satisfactoria
                    toast({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'Registro actualizado'
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {           //SI HAY ALGÚN ERROR
                    //registrando los errores recibidos
                    this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
                });/**/
            },

        },
    }

</script>
```

Por último, lo referido al método del controlador al que llega la petición de actualización del registro:

[**UserController@update**]

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::withTrashed()->findOrFail($id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    //...

    //USERNAME
    $user->username = Str::slug($request->name . ' ' . $request->lastname);

    //AVATAR
    //Si existe un valor para este INPUT...
    $hay_foto = '';
    $name_file = '';
    $user_username = '';
    //return $request->all();
    if($request->has('avatar')) {
    //if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    //if($request->avatar) {
        $hay_foto = 'SI hay';
        $user_username = $user->username;
        $extension_file = explode(';', explode('/', $request->avatar)[1] )[0];
        $name_file = $user->username . '.' . $extension_file;
        //Guardando archivo en STORAGE
        $request->avatar->storeAs('public' . '/images/profile', $name_file);
        //$request->file('avatar')->storeAs('public' . '/images/profile', $name_file);
        $user->avatar = $name_file;
    } else {
        $hay_foto = 'NO hay';
    }

    //Si no es NULO
    if( !is_null($request->password) ) {
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
    }
    $user->profile_id = $request->profile_id;
    $user->save();

    return [
        'message' => 'Actualizando el registro con ID => [' . $id . ']',
        'avatar' => $request->avatar,
        'name_file' => $name_file,
        'user_username' => $user_username,
        'hay_foto' => $hay_foto,
    ];
}
```

De primeras, en el método del controlador, he empleado diferentes combinaciones de condiciones para considerar si llega o no un archivo. La única que ha pasado y entrado dentro del IF es la de `if($request->has('avatar'))`. Con las otras dos, nunca me entra en el IF y, por tanto, no saca ni la extensión del archivo que llega, ni forma el nombre posterior del mismo, ni llega a la línea para almacenar el archivo en la carpeta configurada de destino dentro de "./storage/app/public/images/profile".

Bueno, cuando selecciono la nueva imagen ésta, el evento @change es lanzado y termina cargándose, visualmente, la nueva imagen en la etiqueta IMG adecuada para ello. Y se actualiza la propiedad 'avatar' dentro del objReg, objeto que es pasado en la petición hacia el método "update" del controlador.

En la siguiente imagen, gracias a Vue Devtools, se ve como en la variable "avatar", se carga la imagen actual del usuario precedida de su ruta total, mientras que "objReg.avatar" almacena únicamente el nombre de la imagen actual:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras elegirse y cargarse una nueva imagen, se puede observar que los dos valores se actualizan con esa nueva imagen seleccionada en formato Base64:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo parece correcto entonces. Pero, cuando, pulso el botón para actualizar el registro con sus datos y la nueva imagen con el propósito de almacenarla en la carpeta asignada tras modificarle su nombre, lo que pasa es que me saltan estos errores:

- Como respuesta, recibo este mensaje de excepción

  {message: "Call to a member function storeAs() on string",…}
      exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"

Esto se refiere a esta línea del método del controlador:

```
$request->avatar->storeAs('public' . '/images/profile', $name_file);
```

Por otro lado, dentro de la consola del navegador, me aparece esto otro:

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Sé que el archivo de imagen llega porque, aparte de ver que está cargado como se ve en las imágenes que he puesto, si comento la línea dónde se produce el error y descomento la de `return $request->all();`, recibo todos los datos enviados, entre ellos el `$request->avatar` con su contenido en Base64.

Como se puede observar, en la etiqueta FORM no he puesto ni el `method="post"`, ni el `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.
He probado a poner lo del ENCTYPE en el FORM pero el error sigue saliendo.

Entonces, ya no sé que hacer. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? ¿Alguien ve cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error creo que te está dando porque toma `$request->avatar` como un string.   Debes usar `$request->file('avatar')` para que lo tome como archivo.
No entendí lo que quieres hacer con la extensión, pero hay un método `getClientOriginalExtension();` que obtiene la extensión por tí.
Finalmente, si quieres especificar un disco, pásalo como tercer parámetro. Primero la carpeta, segundo el nombre y tercero el disco.
Algo así:

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
    $hay_foto = 'SI hay';
    $extension_file = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $name_file = $user->username . '.' . $extension_file;
    $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('images/profile', $name_file, 'public');
    $user->avatar = $name_file;
}
```

No he usado casi Vue, pero creo que en la llamada axios debes agregar el encabezado 'multipart/form-data' para que se codifiquen los datos que forman el cuerpo de la solicitud de manera correcta:

```
axios({
    method: 'put',
    url: url,
    data: this.objReg,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        // ...
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        // ...
    });
```

Comment: Parece ser que, aunque cargue un archivo antes de pulsar el botón de enviar, el controlador no interpreta nunca que es un archivo sino que lo recibe como un STRING. Supongo que, por eso, como decía en la pregunta, si pongo `if($request->hasFile('avatar'))`, nunca entra dentro de ese condicional y no llega a almacenar la imagen.

Comment: Si pongo tanto `if($request->has('avatar'))` como `if($request->has('avatar'))`, si entra en el IF pero, entonces, el error se produce en `$request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension()` con un mensaje de "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null". Supongo que el null es porque, igual, `$request->file('avatar')` lo considera como `null` y entonces no puede aplicar la función para sacar la extensión.

Comment: Entonces, supongo que el sistema no está interpretando que le estoy mandando un archivo en Base64 sino que, para él, solamente es un string largo ¿Por qué? ... Recuerdo que estoy mandando la petición por Axios con el método de PUT por lo que en el FORM no tengo ni el `method="post"`, ni el ENCTYPE. ¿Acaso, para que Laravel interprete que le estoy mandando un archivo la petición tiene que ser POST, osea, que tengo que hacer un `axios.post`? ¿Osea, sería necesario `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` y un `axios.post`?

Comment: @zacktagnan edité la respuesta, seguramente el problema está en como se están codificando los datos que envías por axios. Vi tu respuesta, pero no creo que sea en el backend donde tenjas que atajar este error, sino arreglarlo en el frontend.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente, a la espera de que alguien más sabio o con más experiencia lo confirme, deduzco que el sistema de Laravel necesita de que el FORM sea enviado por POST y supongo también que debe incluirse el ENCTYPE dentro de él.

Todo para que el contenido del INPUT FILE sea considerado como un archivo y no como simple STRING que es como llega a mi controlador al haber sido enviado con `axios.put`. Por ese motivo, se produce el error al querer aplicar el `storeAs` ya que, para el sistema se está queriendo aplicar algo que es para archivos y no para cadenas.

Así que, siguiendo con la intención de efectuar un `axios.put` desde el componente de Vuejs hacia el método del controlador, he llegado a solventar el problema empleando el paquete de **[Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)**.

De esta forma, por medio de este paquete, el STRING que constituye el código en Base64 es convertido a archivo al que se le asigna una ruta y un nombre nuevos, guardo la reseña del nombre del archivo en el campo de la tabla y problema resuelto.

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

    if($request->avatar) {
        $extension_file = explode(';', explode('/', $request->avatar)[1] )[0];
        $name_file = $user->username . '-' . time() . '.' . $extension_file;
        //Convirtiendo el STRING recibido en archivo de imagen asignando nombre y ruta
        Image::make($request->avatar)->save(storage_path($this->stor_path_img_profiles) . $name_file);
        $user->avatar = $name_file;
        //Borrando anterior avatar...
        $this->deleteFile($last_avatar_name_file);
    }
```